# Listar arquivo do banco de dados e colocar uma nova linha após um certo número

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, estilo-de-codificação, inserir

Eu estou há dias tentando encontrar uma pequena solução:

Exemplo:

Eu tenho esse código:

```
//LISTAR AS PLAYLISTS
$dados_playlist = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM playlists where codigo = '".$_POST["playlists"]."'"));
```

No momento em que ela for listada, eu preciso colocar 1 comando `(".$hora."".$minuto.")` após um certo número que o usuário escolher.

Exemplo:

Lista normal:

```
1. Música 
2. Música 
3. Música 
4. Música 
5. Música 
6. Música
```

Agora, exemplo de como eu preciso deixar após ela ser listada:

```
1. Música 
2. Música 
3. Música 
".$hora."".$minuto."
4. Música 
5. Música 
6. Música 
".$hora."".$minuto."
```

(no caso acima o usuário selecionou: executar hora certa a cada 3 músicas)

Após isso, eu vou salvar essa lista em um arquivo temporário --> executar uma cron para que essa `".$hora."".$minuto."` sejam faladas em um player

Comment: Como você está gerando essa lista depois de buscar os dados do banco?

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e inclua qualquer informação necessária.

Comment: Não sei como editar

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 1;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM playlists where codigo = '".$_POST["playlists"]."'")) )
{
    if( $count == $escolha_usuario1 )
    {
      echo "HORAMINUTO";
    }

    if( $count == $escolha_usuario2 )
    {
      echo "HORAMINUTO";
    }

    if( $count == $escolha_usuario3 )
    {
      echo "HORAMINUTO";
    }

    $count++;
}
```